# Manage a resource via REST API

Tags: api

I'm writing a plugin to manage the display of some resources accessed via a REST API.

I've set up some rewrite rules to get the correct parameters to send via the API, and some shortcodes that retrieve the data and display the views. But I feel like this is not a good way to do it.

For example I have this rewrite rule:

```
/object/param1/param2/param3
```

And the shortcode in that page use `param1`, `param2` and `param3` to call a specific endpoint and build the page.

What do you think of this approach? Could it be improved in some way?

Thank you for your inputs.

### Update (after suggestion by TheDeadMedic)

In particular, as an example, I felt there was something wrong when I had to create a dynamic title for each object. The title in WordPress is built before the content is parsed (in my case, before the shortcode made the call to the API). So I added a filter to `request` to parse the request, make the request to the API, save it somewhere and pass it to the shortcode.
As a first step, I'd like to streamline this process in some way.

Comment: This is a very open, opinion-based question. I understand there's always the hesitation of "is this the right way", but what about when there is no "right" way? Perhaps you could narrow the scope of what concerns you/post some code you're unsure of/elaborate on your setup.

Comment: Thank you @TheDeadMedic. I've updated the question with a specific example :)

Comment: Please show us some code and tell where you got stuck. Currently it's too vague to get answered.